# How do you start a timer when two objects touch each other(without pixels ever overlapping (simply side by side))?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, collision-detection, rect

I'm using imgData to check if the alpha value of the pixels that surround any object = 255 ( and is therefore opaque) and then if so my moving objects (2 rectangles) cannot move into them (i.e. a wall). Because of this I can't use the rectsCollide function to check if they touch (because that requires an instance where the pixels overlap which my method does not allow). So in a 2 step question I need to know how to check if these two rectangles are touching and 2 if they are how to start a timer when they touch. I'll show you my jsfiddle so that you can see how I check for collision detection...

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/22r0L6a4/
```

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but in your JSFiddle, it decided to log an error: `init() is not defined`.

Comment: thank you that line is not supposed to be there here is the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/22r0L6a4/1/